# How to convert DATETIME from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS. to YYYY-MM using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Using a platform that supports Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, Informix, PostgreSQL
and ANSI SQL dialects.

I need to be able to group customer sales by year and month. The desired date format is YYYY-MM e.g. 2019-06. The current format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

Below is what I have so far. I have tried many different things but unable to get to work as desired.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Customer Name",
ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS 'Sales'
FROM  "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY "Customer Name"
```

Comment: Just curious, which platform is it that supports Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, Informix, PostgreSQL and ANSI SQL dialects?

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY will not return any duplicates.

Comment: It’s a reporting platform called Zoho Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data type is a string, you can use:

```
SELECT LEFT(datecol, 7) as yyyymm, ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS Sales
FROM  "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY LEFT(datecol, 7);
```

If the value is stored as a date/time data type, use date functions, such as:

```
SELECT YEAR(datecol), MONTH(datecol), ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS Sales
FROM  "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY YEAR(datecol), MONTH(datecol);
```

To get the values in one column, you can use `format()`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(datecol, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm
```

Or `extract()`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year_month from datecol) as yyyymm
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is there a way to merge the two columns? I need the date to be one column. I also need the month to be shown with two digits MM e.g. month 5 to show as 05. My desired result is YYYY-MM e.g 2019-05 so that I can use the GROUP BY and ORDER BY functions e.g. show last 6 months worth of sales by month

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the SELECT EXTRACT worked. Now I am having an issue with the query showing the same month multiple times for the same customer             
  ```SELECT
   "Customer Name",
   EXTRACT(year_month FROM "Date") AS Month,
   ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS 'Sales'
FROM  "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY "Date",
   "Customer Name" ```

Comment: @GROUP BY `EXTRACT(year_month FROM "Date"), "Customer Name"`.

Answer (score 0):

If datatype of datecol is timestamp, you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(datecol,'YYYY-MM'), 
    ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS Sales
FROM "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datecol,'YYYY-MM');
```

Or, if it is stored in text/ varchar2 format:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datecol,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM'), 
    ROUND(SUM("Price Ex"), 2) AS Sales
FROM "ZOHO-0006 Invoice Lines" 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datecol,'YYYY-MM');
```

Also, you no need to do 'distinct' explicitely. 'Group by' operation takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks Shantanu. I'm using a reporting platform called Zoho Analytics. It says that it supports Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, Informix, PostgreSQL and ANSI SQL dialects. The data type is datetime so I used your first suggestion. I got a result of 'Your SQL Query is not supported in Zoho Analytics'.